How to create Time Entry records in NetSuite using SuiteScript?
I am trying to create a Time Entry record on a project task using suitescript. But it returns a FEATURE_DISABLED error: "type":"error.SuiteScriptError","name":"FEATURE_DISABLED","message":"The feature 'Timesheets' required to access this page is not enabled in this account.","id":"","stack":["anonymous(N/serverRecordService)","execute(/SuiteScripts/time_entry_test.js:47)"]
I wrote this code. The error is thrown when executing rec.save() line. I would also like to know how to use setValue() method for the field "Duration" (field ID : hours). I tried with values like 4:00 and 4:00:00 but it doesn't accept them. How can I enter hours and minutes to this field?
var rec = record.create(
            {
                type: record.Type.TIME_ENTRY, 
                isDynamic: true
            }
        );
        
        rec.setValue({
            fieldId: 'employee',
            value: 1962,
            ignoreFieldChange: true
        });
        
        rec.setValue({
            fieldId: 'customer',
            value: 2069,
            ignoreFieldChange: true
        });
        
        rec.setValue({
            fieldId: 'casetaskevent',
            value: 1227,
            ignoreFieldChange: true
        });
        
        
        rec.setValue({
            fieldId: 'hours',
            value: 5,
            ignoreFieldChange: true
        });
        
        var trackTime = rec.save();


Try with the following code, you need to use 'timebill' and for the duration/hours you need to use a string with the format: 'hh:mm' and minutes can only be in multiple of 15 mins, NetSuite automatically round the time if you enter something different.
require(['N/action', 'N/record'], function(action, record) {

    var rec = record.create({
        type: 'timebill',
        isDynamic: true
    });
    rec.setValue({
        fieldId: 'employee',
        value: 104
    });
    rec.setValue({
        fieldId: 'location',
        value: 312
    });
    rec.setValue({
        fieldId: 'hours',
        value: '2:15'
    });

    //set the rest of your fields

    var recordId = rec.save();


});


When entering the value- "2:15", NetSuite returns this error :
{"type":"error.SuiteScriptError","name":"INVALID_FLD_VALUE","message":"You have entered an Invalid Field Value 2:15 for the following field: hours","id":"","stack":["anonymous(N/serverRecordService)"
Looks like we have to use decimal values like 1.5 and such to indicate 1 hour and 30 minutes.
Then when I fix the "hours" field error, when executing the script a new error was shown:
"type":"error.SuiteScriptError","name":"INVALID_SUBSIDIARY_COMBINATION","message":"Invalid Subsidiary Combination"

So, you are using one world NetSuite version, each subsidiary has its own records, it the records you are setting on the time entry does not belong to the same subsidiary, it will not work. Try to use values from a time entry that already exist on the UI.

I solved the subsidiary error by manually setting field value to the 'subsidiary' field.  'record.type.TIME_BILL' worked instead of TIME_ENTRY. Thanks for the help Emerson!
